# twice call avformat_find_stream_info() crashed

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

My version of FFmpeg is 4.4.
There is a logic in my code that calls avformat_find_stream_info() twice continuously, but I don't understand why it crashed here. I tried single-step debugging but it didn't work out. Here is my simply code that can be run directly:

```
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

int main()
{
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_DEBUG);
    const char* in_filename_a = "aoutput.aac";
    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx_a = NULL;
    int ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_a, in_filename_a, 0, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input_a %s", in_filename_a);
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "before ifmt_ctx_a=0x%x\n", ifmt_ctx_a->streams[0]);
    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_a, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find input_a stream info");
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "after ifmt_ctx_a=0x%x\n", ifmt_ctx_a->streams[0]);
    /// crashed here
    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_a, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find input_a stream info");
        return -1;
    }

}
```

[image: call stack]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "crashed" ? Did it throw a SEGV (Segmentation fault) ? Did it just exit ? You have to be more specific. Also, did you try with multiple different files ?

Comment: Are you sure nb_streams is gt 0?

Comment: It's a Segmentation fault. I have tried with multiple different files. nb_strams is 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are few hints that imply that we shouldn't execute `avformat_find_stream_info` twice.

- The documentation says: *"examined packets may be buffered for later processing."*
  There is a change that the first execution buffers few packets, and the second execution tries to buffer the packets again without allocating additional space.
- The console prints logging messages as:

> Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:65696 seeks:4 nb_streams:1
> After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 27420 bytes read:65696 seeks:4 frames:50

The messages imply that the position advances from `0` to `27420`. The address of `ifmt_ctx_a->streams[0]` is the same, but the execution of the first `avformat_find_stream_info` did some seeking (so the second execution is not the same as the first one).

- Using the debugger, we can see that `ifmt_ctx_a->pb[0].buf_ptr` is increased after the first execution of `avformat_find_stream_info`.

---

Note:

- I don't know if the crash is normal behavior or a bug in Libavformat library.
  I didn't try looking at the source code of Libavformat.

---

For reading twice, you may close and reopen `ifmt_ctx_a`:

```
avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx_a);   
ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_a, in_filename_a, 0, 0);
```

I don't see any reason to do that...

---

Other option is opening another AVFormatContext:

```
AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx_a = NULL;
int ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_a, in_filename_a, 0, 0);
if (ret < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input_a %s", in_filename_a);
    return -1;
}

ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_a, NULL);
if (ret < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not find input_a stream info");
    return -1;
}

//Opening another AVFormatContext:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx_a2 = NULL;
ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_a2, in_filename_a, 0, 0);
if (ret < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input_a %s", in_filename_a);
    return -1;
}

ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_a2, NULL);
if (ret < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not find input_a stream info");
    return -1;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```